# Golang display static HTML template while waiting for data to load

Tags: http, go, dynamic, go-html-template

I have a route set up which responds with a dynamic HTML template.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
)

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    showWwResult, _ := GetWw()
    showHoursResult, _ := GetHours()

    type Data struct {
        ShowWwResult   []IssueResult
        ShowHoursResult Page
    }

    data := Data{showWwResult, showHoursResult}

    var templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/index.html", "templates/ww.html", "templates/hours.html"))
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "indexPage", data)
}
```

My problem is, it takes a very long time to gather the data and the page waits for this to return before rendering the HTML.

How can I get it to return *something*, anything, while I wait for `GetWw()` and `GetHours()` to finish? Is there any way to display the static part of my HTML template and then populate the page with `ShowWwResult` and `ShowHoursResult` when they're ready?

Comment: I think the best you can do is serve a redirect page with a "please wait" message, but I'm not a HTTP expert...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the best way is to serve the template then populate it using ajax calls to an endpoint that returns json with the data you want to use.